# Contract which reproduce OutOfOffset

Tags: solidity, evm

I want to create a contract so that when `eth_call` is called, the contract returns EVM error: [OutOfOffset](https://docs.rs/evm/latest/evm/enum.ExitError.html#variant.OutOfOffset)

Is there a way to make a contract that reproduces this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

contract OutOfOffset {
    function test(address target) public {
        assembly {
          calldatacopy(0, 0, calldatasize())
          let result := delegatecall(gas(), target, 0, calldatasize(), 0, 0)
          returndatacopy(0, 0, add(returndatasize(), 40))
       }
    }
}
```

```
contract.methods.test('0xF53cC0eF22a093436BB53478b6B3FA8922264a70').call()

//Returned error: Ok(OutOfOffset)
```